# Relation between incline angle of a cylinder filled with water, at which the water would spill

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geometry, volume

We are given a cylinder, that is filled with water. It is inclined by an angle "beta", for which the water from the cylinder would spill. What is the relation between the volume of water in the cylinder? Can the angle be expressed as a function (or relation) of the volume of water in this cylinder?

[image]

So here's what I discovered:
Using integration, I was able to get the volume of a "sliced cylinder, which is the shape the water would take if the water has more than half the volume of the cylinder:
[image]

V=3.14*r^2*((h1+h2/2))

And for cases, for which the volume of the water is less than a half of the cylinder's volume, I found this formula for a cylindrical wedge:
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalWedge.html

This is my basis. I've tried multiple ways of expressing beta with arc-functions through trigonometry and similar triangles with additional constructions, but I'm pretty sure I'm running around in circles and can't escape tautology - so I won't mention those

But this is as far as I've come. I appreciate you reading this problem in advance. I looked for a similar problem online, but couldn't find one. Any help would be appreciated; thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think mathematical-physics and algebraic-geometry are appropriate tags. (The description of the tag algebraic-geometry should include whether the intended meaning really is the branch of mathematics called "algebraic geometry". In any case, other questions with that tag seem to assume it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second diagram, if $h_1$ is the greatest height and $h_2$ the smaller then the volume is as you wrote, but the bracket should be around $h_1+h_2$.

If the volume of the blue liquid in your top diagram is a fraction $f$ of the full volume, e.g. $\frac{3}{4}$ , since the height of the cylinder with the blue liquid in is $h_1$, then

$$\pi r^2 \frac{h_1+h_2}{2} = f \pi r^2 h_1$$

and you can get $h_1 -h_2 = 2h_1(1-f)$.

The angle $\beta$ is also the angle between the top of the blue liquid and the top of the cylinder so it seems you can get $tan \beta = \frac{h_1 - h_2}{2r} = h_1 (\frac{1-f}{r})$ where $r$ is the radius.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I came to as well, but I'm not sure if I can't derive a more in-depth relation. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Relation between incline angle of a cylinder filled with water, at which the water would spill**

It's not necessary to take into account the volumes to determine when the water will spill.  Consider instead the point ($P_0$) defined as the intersection between the water level and the axis through the center of the container.  Notice that: 1) by symmetry, $P_0$ stays at the same location within the cylinder regardless of the tilt; and, 2) the water will spill whenever $P_0$ is at the same level as the edge of the container.  From this, calculating the spill angle ($\beta$) only requires working out triangle with the edge and this point as a corner.

If the water is filled to a distance $z$ from the top of the cylinder of radius $r$, then using your definition of $\beta$,

$$\tan(\beta) = z/r$$

Here's a picture that illustrates this:

[image]

If the water is low enough so that the surface is not symmetric, then this method will not work and you'll need to calculate the volume of the wedge of water mostly along the edge of the cup.

**What is the relation between the volume of water in the cylinder? Can the angle be expressed as a function (or relation) of the volume of water in this cylinder?**

No, there is no relation between the *volume* and the *spill angle* ($\beta$).

The spill angle only depends on the radius of the cylinder ($r$) and distance from the top of the water in the vertical cylinder ($z$), but not the volume.  For example, consider two cylinders with the same radii, but one is short cylinder, and the other is very tall, say 100x taller, so 100x the volume, but both will have the same spill angle if filled to the same distance from the top.

(Of course, one can then remove $r$ from the equation and replace it with a combination of $V$ and $h$, but I'm not considering that as being included in a "relation between".)

Comment: The two answers so far agree with each other, as $z=(1-f)h_1$, it's an interesting method, especially using the fact that P stays at the same place, is there a way to see this for sure?

Comment: @JohnHunter: It's just a symmetry argument, that the water that flows to the right comes from the left, and that the wedge that's filled is the same shape as the wedge that's emptied.

Comment: Yes, good method, one upvote here